# How to set user read only tables in public schema in PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql

I created a new database "employee" then created 3 new tables in public schema.

I connect postgreSQL with jdbc, then I try to print all tables names with postgres user. But there are 323 tables in console, and the 3 tables created by me are between 301-303. I want the user to read only tables in public schema.

This is the code for print table name.

```
    try{
        DatabaseMetaData md = connect.getMetaData();
        ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
        while (rs.next()) {
            //tmp.add(rs.getString(3));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
        }
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if I got right what you mean - but you might try `md.getTables(null, null, "%", new String[] { "TABLE" });`

Comment: Thanks, It work for me. how do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: Reading documentation ([getTables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29), [getTableTypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTableTypes%28%29)) - and sufficient experience in the matter to get a feeling what to pick from it...

Comment: Thanks again for your help.